# Conditional statements in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I've just used CasperJS for my project. Its grammar is clear and easy to learn. But diving through its documentation, I've never found anything about conditional statements. For example, it may be useful if we can use CasperJS in the following manner:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var no_error = false;

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    no_error = true;
});

if (no_error) {
    casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
        this.echo(this.getTitle());
    });
}

casper.run();
```

Is there any way to customize CasperJS to work like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible otherwise such synchronous functions like `casper.exists` don't make sense.

In your example `no_error` could never be `true`, because the `casper.start` callback is executed asynchronously at a time when `if (no_error)` is long evaluated.

You have to nest some steps (all `wait*` and `then*` functions are steps) to do this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var no_error = false;

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    no_error = true;
});

casper.then(function(){
    if (no_error) {
        casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
            this.echo(this.getTitle());
        });
    }
});

casper.run();
```

You can nest step functions, but you have to keep in mind that you should not use a synchronous function after a step, because the it will be executed the other way around.

```
casper.then(function(){
    casper.thenOpen('http://phantomjs.org', function() {
        this.echo("1: " + this.getTitle());
    });
    this.echo("2: " + this.getTitle());
});
```

will print first 2 and then 1.

### Synchronous

If the condition data is returned synchronously then you can evaluate it directly

```
casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
    var array = this.evaluate(function(){....});
    if (array && array.length > 2) {
        this.thenOpen(...);
    }
});
```

There is simply no need for an additional step.

### Asynchronous

This is where it gets interesting. If for example you have to trigger a long running script in page context (it's not limited to the page context), you will have to wait for its completion in casper context. You will need an indicator variable.

```
casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
    longRunningFunction(function callback(){
        window.__someIndicator = true;
    });
});

casper.waitFor(function check(){
    return this.evaluate(function(){
        return !!window.__someIndicator;
    });
}, function then(){
    this.thenOpen(...);
}, function onTimeout(){
    this.echo("failed");
    this.thenOpen(...); // open something else
});
```

Sometimes you don't have a possible callback. In this case the DOM will probably change and you have to wait for those changes.

### Conclusion

The example in the first snippet is not really useful and should be exchanged for one of the other approaches.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough information. :) By the way, would you please tell me what wrong with this issue in CasperJS: https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/1046. I tried to use SlimerJS instead of PhantomJS for CasperJS, but it's fruitless.